# How to remove border around the DataGrid in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How do i remove the border around the Data grid in silverlight when i try BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" it gets rid of the broder on right left and bottom of the grid but not the top i think thats the header border or something but unsure i have also removed headers HeadersVisibility="None" 
would be great if someone could help.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight 2 Beta 2 the generated DataGrid is surrounded by a border. Unfortunately, the removal of this border cannot be accomplished by simply setting a property on the DataGrid. To remove this, the definition of the DataGrid style or "skin" will need to be overridden.

The appearance for each Silverlight control (FrameworkElement) is defined within a ControlTemplate. Using Styles, this template can be overridden within your application with a set of customized XAML code. Default XAML definitions are found within the Silverlight Control Styles and Templates documentation. Specific to this topic, XAML definitions for the DataGrid are found in the DataGrid Styles and Templates documentation.

In the DataGrid XAML, look for the Template definition. Once this has been located, note that the RootElement of the the DataGrid is surrounded by three distinct Border elements.

These elements are likely the items that need to be removed. To start the customization, the style XAML for the DataGrid will need to be added as a new resource into our application. I'm going to add this directly to my UserControl, but it could also be added to the Application resources (in App.xaml).

To add the XAML to the UserControl create a new node named UserControl.Resources and copy the DataGrid XAML into it (use the handy "Copy Code" link on the documentation web page).

The namespace definitions for the DataGrid and the Resource must match. In the copied XAML the namespace is local:DataGrid. The default namespace generated by the Visual Studio tool is my:DataGrid. In the above example, I changed all references of local to my.

The next item to take care of is that the Style must have a Key. This is used to map a Framework element (our DataGrid) to a specific style definition. I've given the style a key of TestGrid which is used in the following DataGrid definition.

At this point, when you run the application the DataGrid should appear exactly as it did before (we haven't changed anything yet).

Before I start removing the definitions for the Border elements, I want to make sure that these are the culprits. To do this, I'm going to change their colors to something a little more obvious.

Running the application, I get the a screen

Zooming in, it's obvious how these elements take part in the display of the DataGrid.

Removing the Border elements from the XAML generates the desired results.

Hopefully, this not only provides a reference for how to remove the border from a DataGrid, but also provides a quick introduction to the possibilities available for customizing Silverlight controls.

Copied from: http://devcenter.auburnrandall.com/Default.aspx?type=post&id=52

Comment: I was looking at that earlier however he doesnt provide the xaml code and images are broken -_-

Answer (score 1):

The element you are seeing it is a `Rectangle` called `ColumnHeadersAndRowsSeparator`. Just create a `Style` without it:

```
    <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="#AAEAEFF4" />
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#00FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="DragIndicatorStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <!-- TODO: Change the TargetType to Control when the fix Jolt bugs 18719 is verified -->
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#7FFFFFFF" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <!-- TODO: Change the TargetType to Control when the fix Jolt bugs 18719 is verified -->
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Grid>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SortStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unsorted" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="SortAscending">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1.0"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="SortDescending">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1.0"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).ScaleY" Duration="0" To="-.9"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#66808080" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" >
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>

                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

                                        <Path Grid.Column="1" Name="SortIcon" Fill="#7FFFFFFF" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0" Stretch="Uniform" Width="8" Margin="4,0,0,0" Data="F1 M -5.215,6.099L 5.215,6.099L 0,0L -5.215,6.099 Z ">
                                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".9" ScaleY=".9" />
                                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="DropLocationIndicatorStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3F4346"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Vertical" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="2">
                            <Grid Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <!--Start: TopLeftHeaderTemplate-->
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopLeftHeaderTemplate" TargetType="localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Grid Name="Root">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                                <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                            </Border>
                                            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="1" Height="1" Fill="#FFDBDCDC" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                    <!--End: TopLeftHeaderTemplate-->

                                    <!--Start: TopRightHeaderTemplate-->
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopRightHeaderTemplate" TargetType="localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Grid Name="RootElement">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                                <Rectangle Stretch="Fill">
                                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                    <!--End: TopRightHeaderTemplate-->
                                </Grid.Resources>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader Name="TopLeftCornerHeader" Template="{StaticResource TopLeftHeaderTemplate}" Width="22" />
                                <localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Name="ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader Name="TopRightCornerHeader" Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource TopRightHeaderTemplate}" />
                                 <!-- HERE IT IS THAT LINE YOU SEE -->                                                                       
                                <!--<Rectangle Name="ColumnHeadersAndRowsSeparator" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="1" Height="1" Fill="#FFC9CACA"/>-->

                                <localprimitives:DataGridRowsPresenter Name="RowsPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                                <Rectangle Name="BottomRightCorner" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
                                <Rectangle Name="BottomLeftCorner" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                <ScrollBar Name="VerticalScrollbar" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="18" Margin="0,-1,-1,-1"/>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle Name="FrozenColumnScrollBarSpacer" />
                                    <ScrollBar Name="HorizontalScrollbar" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="18" Margin="-1,0,-1,-1"/>
                                </Grid>

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" CornerRadius="2" Background="#8CFFFFFF" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```